# JQuery Not Working in an Echoed Search Result

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code echoed as a search result, however the click event does not work, any suggestions ?

```
<script>function BiologyFunction(){ $("#Biology").click(function(){ $("#squbomain").animate({ height:'242px'}); $("#minus").hide(); $("#menu").hide(); $("#keywords").hide(); $("#home").animate({ left:'178px', top:'71px' }); $("#search").animate({ left:'120px', top:'119px' }); $("#search").show(); $("#plus").show(); $('#searchterm').val('Biology').keyup(); }</script>

<div id="Biology" style='margin: 1px; width: 242px; height: 242px; float: left; background-image: url("squbo/content/images/biologysqubo.png"); background-size: cover;' onclick="BiologyFunction()">
    <div style="left: 0px; top: 162px; width: 242px; height: 80px; position: relative; z-index: 3; background-color: rgb(45, 79, 1);">
        <div style="left: 20px; top: 20px; width: 202px; height: 40px; line-height: 75%; position: absolute;">
            <div style="font-size: 15px; display: inline;">
                Biology
            </div>
            <div style="font-size: 12px; display: inline;">
                  is the scientific study of Life including its structure, function and evolution
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code it is generated from in the search results while loop:

```
        elseif ( $result['template'] =="4info" )
            {
                echo "
                    <script>function {$result['title']}Function(){ $(\"#{$result['title']}\").click(function(){ $(\"#squbomain\").animate({ height:'242px'}); $(\"#minus\").hide(); $(\"#menu\").hide(); $(\"#keywords\").hide(); $(\"#home\").animate({ left:'178px', top:'71px' }); $(\"#search\").animate({ left:'120px', top:'119px' }); $(\"#search\").show(); $(\"#plus\").show(); $('#searchterm').val('{$result['title']}').keyup(); }</script>
                    <div id=\"{$result['title']}\" onclick =\"{$result['title']}Function()\" style=\"width:242px; height:242px; float:left; margin:1px; background-image:url('squbo/content/images/{$result['image']}'); background-size:cover;\" >
                        <div style=\"width:242px; height:80px; position:relative; left:0px; top:162px; z-index:3; background-color:#{$result['color']};\">
                            <div style=\"width:202px; height:40px; position:absolute; left:20px; top:20px; line-height:75%;\">
                                <div style=\"display:inline; font-size:15px;\">
                                    {$result['title']}
                                </div>
                                <div style=\"display:inline; font-size:12px;\">
                                     {$result['description']}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ";
            }
```

To see the current code  please go here and search for Biology:
http://squbo.com/mon07apr.php

Comment: it looks like you're missing a closing `}` tag.

Comment: Here is the code it is generated from in the search results while loop:

Comment: Yeah... When I put your code in a syntax highlighter, you were missing a closing `}` on your whole script.

Comment: use firebug(or similar); and do multiline for easy-debug

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<script>function {$result['title']}Function(){ $(\"#{$result['title']}\").click(function(){ $(\"#squbomain\").animate({ height:'242px'}); $(\"#minus\").hide(); $(\"#menu\").hide(); $(\"#keywords\").hide(); $(\"#home\").animate({ left:'178px', top:'71px' }); $(\"#search\").animate({ left:'120px', top:'119px' }); $(\"#search\").show(); $(\"#plus\").show(); $('#searchterm').val('{$result['title']}').keyup(); }</script>
```

To

```
<script>function {$result['title']}Function(){ $(\"#{$result['title']}\").click(function(){ $(\"#squbomain\").animate({ height:'242px'}); $(\"#minus\").hide(); $(\"#menu\").hide(); $(\"#keywords\").hide(); $(\"#home\").animate({ left:'178px', top:'71px' }); $(\"#search\").animate({ left:'120px', top:'119px' }); $(\"#search\").show(); $(\"#plus\").show(); $('#searchterm').val('{$result['title']}').keyup(); });}</script>
```

You were missing `); }`

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r84Ju/):